# Try/catch syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, try-catch, mysql-error-1064

How can I not get the right syntax for a simple try/catch?
Do I have to do anything more?

All I get is error 1064...

```
BEGIN TRY
SELECT * FROM NonExistentTable;
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
SELECT * FROM ExistingTable;
END CATCH;
GO

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRY
SELECT * FROM NonExistentTable' at line 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have `TRY/CATCH` functionality. You can use [handlers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare-handler.html).